# Named Ranges, Cell References and Validation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If I have two cells and a named range "Mexico":

`A1` contains the string: "Mexico"
`A2` is the cell that has required data validation (drop down list).

I want `A2`'s validation reference to be dynamic, in the sense that I can it reference it to `A1`; converting the string "Mexico" to a named range Mexico.

I tried inputting `=INDIRECT(A1)` into the cell's validation window.

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/69651453/test22.xlsx]

Comment: You have quite a few questions that haven't been closed. Have you really not gotten a good answer out of any? If you did, try accepting the correct answers, this will help you get answers in the long run.

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of [INDEX(INDIRECT(“DefinedName”),1)=#REF while INDEX(DefinedName,1) works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945672/indexindirectdefinedname-1-ref-while-indexdefinedname-1-works)

Comment: I have accepted them. In the sense that I have said "yes" to "was this question useful to you". Maybe I am missing something in closing a question?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the indirect data validation model with a dynamic named range.

Check out [this reference](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/03/01/indirect-and-dynamic-ranges/) to get more info on the subject

Answer (score 0):

in your named range is an error therefore it will not give an actual range. The sheet name in the indirect should be added to the address like this:

`"'list range'!"&ADDRESS(...)`

WIth that in mind you can also just have a single named range that will always turn up with your desired range for the drop down list.

Give it a fixed name (for example rangeCountry) and use that for the data validation. (fixed name, not indirect, that wont work!)